# CSS hover modify self and other class

Tags: css, hover

I know there are a ton of answers on `:hover` effecting other classes.  What I'm trying to do is change the font color of itself (*.footer_status_tex*) and `background-color` of another class (*.footer_status_gear*)

Simplified CSS - Something like this:

**CSS**

```
.footer_status_tex {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
.footer_status_gear {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.footer_status_tex: hover {
    color: #81aaf3;
}
.footer_status_tex:hover .footer_status_gear {
    background-color: #aba51e;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer_status_tex" style="">Hello</div>
<div class="footer_status_gear"></div>
```

Current setup only changes font color.

Thanks

Comment: is `.footer_status_gear` a child element of `.foort_status_tex` ?

Comment: Nope sorry I will add that to desc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to fix the selector `.footer_status_tex: hover`, remove the gap after `:`.

Second, the selector `.footer_status_tex:hover .footer_status_gear` only works if the latter one is a child of the former one.

What you need is `.footer_status_tex:hover + .footer_status_gear` or `~` if the latter one is a sibling of the former one, also the latter one must be placed next to the former one in the DOM.

```css
.footer_status_tex:hover {
  color: #81aaf3;
}

.footer_status_tex:hover + .footer_status_gear {
  background-color: #aba51e;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_status_tex">Hello</div>
<div class="footer_status_gear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `~` adjacent selector to target the adjacent elements

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.footer_status_tex {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer_status_gear {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.footer_status_tex:hover {
  color: #81aaf3;
}

.footer_status_tex:hover ~ .footer_status_gear {
  background-color: #aba51e;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_status_tex" style="">Hello</div>
<div class="footer_status_gear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When posting CSS problems, please also include the associated HTML code as without it, we're can only assess half the problem.

I'm assuming this is your structure: https://codepen.io/barrymcgee/pen/vdGOra?editors=1100#

The reason why the background of `.footer_status_gear` doesn't change is because it's the parent element of the link. A `:hover` pseudo-class can only direct the children of the element to which it is applied.

If the assumption I made about your HTML structure is wrong, please provide it and I'll look again.